# Search object and .push to new location

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to push sentences from one place to another.

It all depends on which keywords are found. If a sentence has two keywords, then it gets pushed to the first one.

- cat - pushes all sentences with cat in them to **keywordsFound.cats**
- dog - pushes all sentences with dog in them to **keywordsFound.dogs**
- hamst - pushes all sentences with hamster in them to **keywordsFound.hamsters**

```js
var data = "I have an oriental cat. I have both a dog and a cat. I always takes care of my American shorthair cat. I have a Birman cat. My parents bought me two Golden Retriever dogs. My dog is a German Shepherd. I always wanted a hamster. I don't have a pet."

var userInput = {
  all: [
    "I have an oriental cat.",
    "I have both a dog and a cat.", //Should only push the first one - dog
    "I always take care of my American shorthair cat.",
    "I have a Birman cat.",
    "My parents bought me two Golden Retriever dogs.",
    "My dog is a German Shepherd.",
    "I always wanted a hamster.",
    "I don't have a pet."
  ],
  keywordsFound: {
    cats: [/*Push all sentences with cat here*/],
    dogs: [/*Push all sentences with dog here*/],
    hamsters: [/*Push all sentences with hamster here*/]
  },
  noKeywordsFound: [],
}

function search(term) {
  if (userInput.all.indexOf(term) !== -1) {
    if (term == 'cat') {
     }
    if (term == 'dog') {
     }
    if (term == 'hamster') {
    }

  } 
  else {
    //Push to noKeywordsFound as an array
  }
}

//Which ever comes first gets pushed
search('cat')
search('dog') //Contains
search('hamster') //Contains
```

Comment: You are calling `search('hamst')` while in the `search` function you are looking for `if (term == 'hamster') {`. You have to correct the test or the call to make it work.

Comment: And to improve your code, use a `switch` instead of several `if`. It's better for read and for performance.

Comment: The code will not work regardless of hamster search text… I'm new to coding and I'm trying to figure it out as I go. I will look into what switch is… I'm still a beginner at this

Comment: The question is not really clear. Why do you need such an irregular structure in first place? Why do you mutate `userInput`?

Comment: @YuryTarabanko I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so you are on the right track using [**indexOf**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) but you are using it on the wrong place(`userInput.all.indexOf(term)`) :)

So what you should do in the `search()` function is:

1) Loop through each element of `userInput.all` - you can do a regular `for` loop or use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to get all the matching sentences.

2) now inside the loop use [**indexOf**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) on each element to check if it contains the search term

3) insert in the desired collection if term is found

So I will slightly change your code like this:

```js
var userInput = {
  all: [
    "I have an oriental cat.",
    "I have both a dog and a cat.", //Should only push the first one - dog
    "I always take care of my American shorthair cat.",
    "I have a Birman cat.",
    "My parents bought me two Golden Retriever dogs.",
    "My dog is a German Shepherd.",
    "I always wanted a hamster.",
    "I don't have a pet."
  ],
  keywordsFound: {
    cats: [],
    dogs: [],
    hamsters: []
  },
  noKeywordsFound: [],
}

function search(term) {
  
  // Here you can do a basic for loop, but I'm using reduce function
  var foundItems = null;
  foundItems = userInput.all.reduce(function(found, current){
    if(~current.indexOf(term)){
      found.push(current);
    }
    return found;
  }, []);
  
  switch(term){
    case 'cat':{
      userInput.keywordsFound.cats = foundItems;
    }break;
    
    case 'dog':{
      userInput.keywordsFound.dogs = foundItems;
    }break;
    
    case 'hamster':{
      userInput.keywordsFound.hamsters = foundItems;
    }break;
  }

}

search('cat');
console.log('sentence with cats')
console.log(userInput.keywordsFound.cats);
search('dog'); 
console.log('sentence with dogs')
console.log(userInput.keywordsFound.dogs);
search('hamster'); 
console.log('sentence with hamsters')
console.log(userInput.keywordsFound.hamsters);
```

Comment: Using a JavaScript `switch cases` for a logic based on the search input `term` entered by the end user.. Don't think it is a good idea because you can get that dynamically with `Object.keys(userInput.keywordsFound).find(k => k.includes(term))` Check my answer

Comment: Yes, using `switch` is not the best option if the input data is coming from user, but it will work in this specific use case. Thanks for pointing that. Anyway your solution is there and if someone needs it, can use it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ES6 arrow functions, the [String.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and the array functions [Array.prototype.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and [Array.prototype.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to determine the proper `key` variable to push: `userInput.keywordsFound[key].push(str)`.

Code:

```js
const userInput = {
    all: ["I have an oriental cat.", "I have both a dog and a cat.", "I always take care of my American shorthair cat.", "I have a Birman cat.", "My parents bought me two Golden Retriever dogs.", "My dog is a German Shepherd.", "I always wanted a hamster.", "I don't have a pet."],
    keywordsFound: {
      cats: [],
      dogs: [],
      hamsters: []
    },
    noKeywordsFound: [],
  },
  search = term => {
    userInput.all.forEach(str => {
      const key = Object.keys(userInput.keywordsFound).find(k => k.includes(term));
      key && str.includes(term) && userInput.keywordsFound[key].push(str);
    });
  };

//Which ever comes first gets pushed
search('cat');
search('dog'); //Contains dog
search('hams'); //Contains hamst

console.log(userInput.keywordsFound);
```